# How To Set ForeignKey As PrimaryKey Using UUID Trait

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-migration

I have 2 table that separate users' login info (***email, username, password***) and general info (***full_name, address, etc***).

I set **users** as parent table with UUID as the *PrimaryKey*, and **profiles** as child table with UUID as the *PrimaryKey & ForeignKey* (I don't know if this is possible, but migration runs without any error).

**users_migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**user_model**

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Traits\UUID;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
  use HasFactory, Notifiable, UUID;

    protected $table = "users";

    public $primaryKey = "id";
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'id',
        'username',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}
```

**profiles_migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('user_id')->primary();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->string('full_name')->unique();
        $table->longText('address')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**profile_model**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "profiles";

    public $primaryKey = "user_id";
    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'user_id',
        'full_name',
        'address',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

}

**register_controller**

```
public function Register(Request $request)
{
    $newUserData = $request->validate(
        [
            'full_name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:30'],
            'email' => ['required', 'unique:users', 'regex:(gmail)'],
            'password' => ['required', 'min:10'],
        ],
        [
            'email.regex' => "Your email must use Gmail as its domain.",
            'term.accepted' => "You must agree to Larasight's Terms and Conditions."
        ]
    );

    User::create([
        'username' => Str::lower($newUserData['full_name']),
        'email' => $newUserData['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($newUserData['password']),
    ]);

    Profile::create([
        'full_name' => $newUserData['full_name'],
    ]);
}
```

Error upon registrating : **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value**

**Question :** How to fill the **user_id** and **full_name** on profiles_table as the user registrates?

Comment: I think you need to use [the save method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) i.e. `User::create(...)->profile()->save(new Profile(..))`. This should associate the profile to the user

Comment: The problem is my trait that will automatically fill the *id* column in users_table with UUID and not me manually. How to get the UUID created by the trait and store it to the profiles_table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing this in an odd way. I would recommend just have an 'id' on your profiles table and have it as the primary. Rather than 'user_id' which is a foreign key be the primary. Anyways, besides that, when you create the Profile object you have not set the primary key. So you would either have to make it nullable in your profiles migration or new up a profile instance without persisting. Lastly, I guess you could just store the User::create() to a variable and pass the id as 'user_id' in the Profile::create function.

```
$user = User::create([
    'username' => Str::lower($newUserData['full_name']),
    'email' => $newUserData['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($newUserData['password']),
]);



Profile::create([
    'user_id' => $user->id,
    'full_name' => $newUserData['full_name'],
]);
```

Comment: That's what I've done before posting this i was using uniqid() manually, now i have no idea how to get that id which is created by the trait.

Comment: The issue you are having is because you are not setting the user_id and it is required in your migration. Try that.

Comment: It is in the answer